# Adding a path to PATH variable

Tags: shell

I have a shell script located under /home/myself/bin directory. I added its path to PATH variable in .profile by adding the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/myself/bin
```

Then I sourced my .profile by the command **source ~/.profile**. Now when I run **sh myscript.sh** command it shows,

```
sh: 0: Can't open myscript.sh
```

Can anyone say me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$PATH` tells your shell where to search for executables.  In your case, `sh` is the executable and `myscript.sh` is just an argument. You need to first make `myscript.sh` executable:

```
 chmod +x /home/myself/bin/myscript.sh
```

Then just run `myscript.sh` (without the `sh`).